# How do I switch seamlessly between multiple routers, behind a router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking, wireless-access-point

I have a router/modem which has a wired connection to a router that has a USB storage attached (and this is the reason this can not be configured as an AP). I'll call this **Router A**.

I have another router attached (wired) to the same router/modem on the third floor. This will be **Router B**.
I cannot connect this router to Router A.

I gave them a different address, but the same subdomain: 192.168.0.x
I gave the wifi from both the same SSID and password and security.

I have 2 problems:

1. It only switches to a different router when it really drops the other router (leaving me with still a lousy connection, as the both reach as far as each others location).
2. I can't reach the attached storage on Router A when connected to Router B.

Problem 1 is my biggest issue.

So my setup is:

```
                      Router A (with attached storage, so cannot be AP)
                   /  192.168.0.A
                  /
Modem/Router ----
192.168.1.1       \
                   \  Router B
                      192.168.0.B
```

Ps. Router B does have Bridge Mode. But I couldn't figure out how to make this work with Router A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will never work well.

**Problem 1**:

Basically you have 2 independent access-points, that don't know about each other.

(That they also happen to be routers is irrelevant for the Wifi perspective.)

Roaming between them will never work.

In order to have proper roaming you need either a mesh of AP's or a central controller with AP's. You have neither.

**Problem 2**:

Because A and B are independent networks that both do NAT toward the main router (and have overlapping ip-ranges) communication from behind one of them to a device behind the other one is technically impossible.

The simple solution would be to put B as AP only and connect it behind A, but you already ruled that out.

The best you can do (for BOTH problems):

I would disable the DHCP on BOTH A and B and connect them to the main router with a LAN port in stead of the WAN port.
This brings BOTH Wifi AP's and ALL LAN ports into the single network (192.168.1.X) of the main router. That will give all devices access to the storage on A. (Make sure you set A and B's own LAN-side ip-address to a fixed ip-address in the 192.168.1.X range that is ouside the DHCP range of the modem/router. A needs that fixed address so our other devices have that fixed ip to find the storage on. A and B both need it so you can still reach their admin-webpage.)

For the Wifi set both AP's to the same name/password combination, but use different channels (or leave the channel secletion on Auto). That will minimize problem 1, but it won't entirely fix it. Without mesh (or a central Wifi controller) it is the best you can do.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Really appreciate your help ‍♂️

Comment: @DanielKoster You're welcome :-)